# Does a Lazarus program need special permissions to run on Windows?

Tags: windows, permissions, lan, lazarus, ubuntu-server

I built a Lazarus program and it's now in exe form.

I am able to run it on two of my computers running XP and Vista.

However, there are other computers as well running XP, Vista and Win7 but I cannot get it to run at all on them.

There are no errors, nothing... Has anyone else had this issue?

The program is connecting to a postgres DB on my LAN server.

Any idea on fixing this is really valued.

NEW INFO:

Maybe I'm wrong but here's a thought... On the development machine, I initially got an error like **libpq.dll* not found when I first tried to connect to postgres. Then after setting the path, it was fine. I'm thinking now if it cannot find that library and that's why it's not able to run.

If this is the case, should my line `Application.OnException:=@CatchErr;` catch the error? If not how else should I check if this dll or anything else is missing?

Comment: Have you added any logging code to see how far your app gets into starting up?

Comment: @MartynA It's I don't have anything specific but I DO have this: `Application.OnException:=@CatchErr;` The thing is that it **NEVER** reports anything. I'm stumped! I just can't imagine this. It **seems like the code never runs**.

Comment: Sounds like you definitely need some start up logging code - FWIW I've found the remote version of CodeSite (www.raize.com) invaluable for this kind of thing.  Re your "new info", if your app is failing before execution reaches Application.Initialize in your .Dpr, I don't think your OnException will ever be called - try deliberately raising an exception before Application.Initialize to check.

Answer (score 3):

First, a sincere and big THANK YOU to Marco and MArtyn for the great tips and guidelines hat got me thinking of this strange issue.

Here's what happened...

I installed a fresh copy of Windows 7 and XP. As usual it did not work.

Then I suspected the old problem of libpq and then I copied libpq.dll from my working OS and put it in the application folder. By the way this machine has no Lazarus or Postgres. The moment I did this, I got my first error message saying that msvcr100.dll was missing.

And then I copied that as well. So the cycle of copy pasting went on for each and every error until I had finally brought these files to my 'non-working'.

- libpq.dll - 9.2.1.12263 - PosgreSQL Access Library
- msvcr100.dll - 10.0.40219.1 - Microsoft C Runtime Library
- ssleay32.dll - 1.0.1.2 - OpenSSL Shared Library
- libeay32.dll - 1.0.1.2 OpenSSL Shared Library
- libintl.dll - 0.18.1.0 - LGPLed libintl for Windows NT/2000/XP/Vista/7

Once these files came in, the problem was gone!
Now the program works great :)

Thanks for all your inputs!

I now have to see what the above files have to say about their licenses as I have to distribute the app to other users. But I'm glad at least we figured out the problem.

Answer (score 2):

No, base Lazarus programs don't require special permissions. Of course it could be that a specific functionality in the program requires special permissions (like access to ports below 1024, access to certain paths etc).

Also be aware that EXE's downloaded from what the system considers insecure sources (internet, certain kinds of shares) might be blocked by default. If that is the case, if you take the properties of the .EXE in windows explorer, there will be an "unblock" button.

Anything network related of course requires proper configuration of the firewall. The popups that query you might not always come, in case of doubt configure the firewall manually.

Comment: postgres uses port 5432 on the server. The exe has full permissions. The firewall is turned off. Still nothing. I just did a fresh installation of XP on a virtual box. Tried running the application on it. It does NOT run. So I'm guessing that some library is missing. Is there some way of finding out if all libs are available for my program?

Comment: "Is there some way of finding out if all libs are available for my program? "  I think you could use a utility like ProcessHacker (SourceForge.Net) to see if it fails to load a required library.